# Newtonsoft JSON deserialization works on local and live environments but not on test for ASP.NET MVC application

Tags: c#, json, asp.net-mvc, json.net

I'm currently working on a project involving the use of a payment gateway. An iframe is used to hold the payment gateway. The url of the iframe is retrieved by sending the POST below.

```cs
ResponseBody b = new ResponseBody();
b.SenderId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderId"];
b.Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayUsername"];
b.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPassword"];
b.PaymentSessionProviderReference = transaction.TransactionRef;
b.AmountInCents = Decimal.ToInt32(purchaseDetails.CartTotal * 100);
b.ReturnURL = redirectorLink;
b.BackgroundColor = "#ffffff";
b.InlineFrame = true;
if ((string)Session["Language"] == "en-EN") { b.Language = "EN"; }

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

 HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("PreparePayment", b);
```

The response to this post will then hold the url to the payment gateway which is then opened in the iframe. Also, the returnLink is also specified in this POST, which is where the gateway will redirect the user (within the iframe) after the user enters their payment details for the payment.

For me to confirm the status of the payment to continue the workflow, I then request the payment through another POST in the action method specified in the returnLink property. This is being done as follows:

```cs
GetPaymentModel b = new GetPaymentModel();
b.SenderId = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SenderId"];
b.Username = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayUsername"];
b.Password = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["PayPassword"];
b.PaymentSessionProviderReference = transaction.TransactionRef;
b.MessageId = null;
b.PaymentId = null;

client.BaseAddress = new Uri(url);

HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsJsonAsync("GetPayment", b);
```

Now this is where the problem begins. The JSON is being returned correctly in all environments. This JSON is then being deserialized as follows:

```cs
string jsonResponse = "";
jsonResponse = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
AvaLogger.WriteLog(jsonResponse);

//Yet to figure out how to log trace on the test server.
ITraceWriter traceWriter = new MemoryTraceWriter();
paymentDetails = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<PaymentDetailsModel>(jsonResponse, 
    new JsonSerializerSettings { TraceWriter = traceWriter, Converters = { new 
    JavaScriptDateTimeConverter() }}
);

AvaLogger.WriteLog("Information For: " + paymentDetails.paymentSessionProviderReference + ". Host message: " + paymentDetails.hostMessage);
```

When logging this information on local and live environments, the log methods log the following information:

```
[24/06/2020 08:38:46] <PaymentResolver>d__12: MoveNext: {"transactionTypeField":0,"authorisationCodeField":"425643","batchNumberField":"","hostCodeField":"000","hostMessageField":"APPROVED","merchantAccountField":"1000","merchantTerminalField":null,"maskedCardNumberField":"444444****4444","detectedCardApplicationField":"VISA","paymentDateField":"2020-06-24T08:38:59","anyField":null,"paymentIdField":153938,"paymentSessionProviderReferenceField":"G2315","paymentStateField":3,"amountInCentsField":2000,"pGDataField":{"paymentGatewayReferenceField":"93177947","emailAddressField":"daniel.falzon@avantechsoftware.com","anyField":null,"PropertyChangedEvent":null},"assignmentsField":[],"PropertyChangedEvent":null}
 LogMode:   NotSet
 UTC TimeStamp:     24/06/2020 06:38:46
 
[24/06/2020 08:38:46] <PaymentResolver>d__12: MoveNext: Information For: G2315. Host message: APPROVED
 LogMode:   NotSet
 UTC TimeStamp:     24/06/2020 06:38:46
```

The JSON is being fully retrieved and the data is being deserialized correctly. However, when it comes to the test environemt, the following occurs:

```
[24/06/2020 09:48:32] <PaymentResolver>d__12: MoveNext: {"transactionTypeField":0,"authorisationCodeField":"316120","batchNumberField":"","hostCodeField":"000","hostMessageField":"APPROVED","merchantAccountField":"1000","merchantTerminalField":null,"maskedCardNumberField":"444444****4444","detectedCardApplicationField":"VISA","paymentDateField":"2020-06-24T09:48:26","anyField":null,"paymentIdField":153949,"paymentSessionProviderReferenceField":"G2333","paymentStateField":3,"amountInCentsField":500,"pGDataField":{"paymentGatewayReferenceField":"93180750","emailAddressField":"daniel.falzon@avantechsoftware.com","anyField":null,"PropertyChangedEvent":null},"assignmentsField":[],"PropertyChangedEvent":null}
 LogMode:   NotSet
 UTC TimeStamp:     24/06/2020 07:48:32
 
[24/06/2020 09:48:32] <PaymentResolver>d__12: MoveNext: Information For: . Host message: 
 LogMode:   NotSet
 UTC TimeStamp:     24/06/2020 07:48:32
```

The JSON is still returned correctly. However, the data isn't being deserialised. Resulting in all the properties of paymentDetails (instance of PaymentDetailsModel shown at the bottom of the post) to remain null.

Is there some kind of server configuration that may be messing with this? Thanks for reading and hope this was informative enough for you guys to give your input!

P.S. I'm trying to figure out how to print the logs of a TraceWriter instance as I'm still relatively new to dealing with APIs on ASP.NET.

For reference:

PaymentDetailsModel:

```cs
 public class PaymentDetailsModel
    {
        [JsonProperty("transactionTypeField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public TransactionTypes transactionType { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("authorisationCodeField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string authorisationCode { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("batchNumberField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string batchNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hostCodeField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string hostCode{ get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("hostMessageField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string hostMessage { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("merchantAccountField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string merchantAccount { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("merchantTerminalField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string merchantTerminal { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("maskedCardNumberField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string maskedCardNumber { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("detectedCardApplicationField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string detectedCardApplication { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("paymentDateField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string paymentDate { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("anyField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public object any { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("paymentIdField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public int paymentId { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("paymentSessionProviderReferenceField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public string paymentSessionProviderReference { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("paymentStateField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public PaymentStates paymentState { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("amountInCentsField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public int amountInCents { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("pGDataField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public PGdataModel pGData { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("assignmentsField", Required = Required.Default, NullValueHandling = NullValueHandling.Ignore)]
        public object[] assignments { get; set; }
        public object PropertyChangedEvent { get; set; }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I created a console app to remove the added complexities of the web application and deserialisation works fine both with a hardcoded JSON string and with JSON retrieved from the API. Could this encourage the fact that this might be an IIS configuration issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So turns out there was a change on the Web.config that changed the Newtonsoft version from 10 to 11 and no errors were being thrown regarding this... *big facepalm moment*. Changing the version to 11 to match with the other environments fixed the issue.